# LIKE clause is not working in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-like

I have a table which have the following columns in SQL Server 2005:

```
DocID   NSN  QTY
-----------------
DHA12    32    5
DSRB23   22   45
TF22     70   23
```

Whenever I perform the following query to get all the NSN which have a DocId that starts with either DSRB or DHA, it gives me empty set:

```
SELECT  DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
  FROM  Orders 
 WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%') 
   AND (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

I guess the problem with having two LIKE clauses because when I delete the last LIKE clause, the query works fine.

Comment: IF you want to search for something that **starts** with a string of char, you should use `LIKE 'DHA%'` - in that case, SQL Server has a chance of using an index that might be present, to speed things up. If you use the expression you have now (`LIKE '%DHA%'`), you search for something that **contains** those three letters anywhere in the string, and SQL Server has no chance at all to use any index - even if it were present.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get an empty result because there is no row in your table where `DocID` is like **both** `%DSRB%` **and** `%DHA%` at the same time. You don't say in your question, but I guess you are expecting to receive the two rows with DocIds `DHA12` and `DSRB23`.

To do this, you need to select rows where `DocID` is like **either** `%DSRB%` **or** `%DHA%`. Try changing the `AND` in your `WHERE` clause to an `OR`:

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%') OR (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

See this [introduction to SQL Logical Operators](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-logical-operators.htm) if you want more examples.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find rows that contain **either** XX **or** YY, you need to use **[OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238518%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)**:

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate 
FROM Orders 
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%')
   OR (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't you want an `OR` in there instead of an `AND`?

Answer (score 1):

There are no rows in your table which contain the string "DSRB" AND contain the string "DHA".

Answer (score 1):

Make it "OR" instead of "AND".  At this point, you're saying both clauses in the "WHERE" have to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need AND? You have no records shown that meet those requirements. I think you may want OR, which should return two records.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%') AND (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

would only match something like "DSRB DHA"

You mean:

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%') OR (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

Or this:

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DSRB%')
UNION
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE (DocID LIKE '%DHA%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sandwiched LIKE is a table scan, so an alternative that performs just as badly (or worse) would be

```
SELECT DocId, NSN, Qty, RequestDate, ReceiveDate
FROM Orders
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(DocID, 'DSRB', ''), 'DHA', '') != DocID
```